# Xcode run script with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a run script in Xcode that I have written in Swift. In the build settings I have a run script whose shell is set to `/bin/sh` and the contents is the single line `./my-script.swift`. That file contains only the lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/xcrun swift
import Foundation
```

If I build for the simulator, everything works just fine. If I build for the device I get a ton of errors along the lines of:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: Could not build module 'Darwin'
>
> :0: Could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:680:2: Unsupported architecture

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Try xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.0 swift perhaps?

Comment: Great! I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's using the iOS device SDK by default (`iPhoneOS`). Try to invoke xcrun by specifying either the `iphonesimulator` or `macosx` SDKs like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator swift

#!/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk macosx swift
```